# jQuery .on('click') does not work with jQuery UI draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-on

I have a question regarding jQuery. I am really new with jQuery, or even javascript for that matter, so please bear with me.

I am using jQuery UI draggable on some divs in my app. The problem is, jQuery .on('click') doesn't seem to work with these divs. I did try to use .click() and it does work. However, the divs are going to be created dynamically, and based on what I've learned it is best to use .on() when we want to use dynamically created elements. Below is my HTML snippet:

```
<div class="book-page">
    <div class="draggable-text">
        <p>First text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="draggable-text">
        <p>Second text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery snippet:

```
$('div.draggable-text').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    delay: 200,
    containment: 'parent'
}).resizable().selectable();

// This one doesn't work
$('div.book-page').on('click', 'div.book-page > div.draggable-text', function () {
    alert('clicked!');
    // some more coding here...
});

// This one works
/*$('div.book-page > div.draggable-text').click(function () {
    alert('clicked!');
    // some more coding here...
});*/
```

And lastly, here is [a link to a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arsyadtaufan/G75qs/) I've created. I really appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks! And sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have some syntax errors with your second one.

Try this:

```
$('div.draggable-text').on('click', function () {
  alert('clicked!');
  // some more coding here...
});
```

Read the syntax for the jQuery 'on' event to understand better what arguments go in.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Cheers!

Comment: well, I just re-tested it again. Your answer works for the elements that already created. But it doesn't work for dynamically created elements. It needs a bit of tweak >> `$('div.book-page').on('click', 'div.draggable-text', function () {` see also in [my js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arsyadtaufan/G75qs/). Anyway, thanks to your answer (and reading the docs) I can solve my prob!

Comment: The reason it happens is because for some reason when using `containment: 'parent'` the parent will stop click events propagation. Have you found a way past that? Same as you, it's important that I delegate the events and not attach them directly to the element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('div.draggable-text').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want bind click event to dinamically created draggable element, your first idea was almost correct.

Here is a fixed code : http://jsfiddle.net/G75qs/3/

```
$('.draggable-text').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    delay: 200,
    containment: 'parent'
}).resizable().selectable();

//Bind click event for all element with class .draggable-text including 
//elements dynamically created
$('.book-page').on('click', '.draggable-text', function () {
    alert('clicked!');
    // some more coding here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Syntax  is incorect try this:

```
$('div.draggable-text').on('click', function () {
alert('clicked......');
// some coding here...
});
```

Check here : http://jsfiddle.net/jS8sK/2/

Answer (score -2):

for Divs that was created dynamically its better to use `.live` for events.

```
$('div.draggable-text').die('click').live('click', function () {
alert('clicked......');
```

Comment: Yeah, but `.live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+, and jQuery docs suggests to use `.on` to _replace_ it. [http://api.jquery.com/live/](http://api.jquery.com/live/)