# How to make an Element Clickable inside a Draggable Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am working on a Drag & Drop Builder using JQuery UI. What I want to do is, when I hover on any Drag-able element, a cross appears, and on clicking that cross, that element needs to be removed. 
Here is my JQuery Code to create a Drag-able Element:

```
var postfix = '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>';
$(".buildbutton").click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    if (id === 'label') {
        var elemHtml = '<div class="draggable"><label contenteditable="true" class="draggable" id="label' + labelCount + '">Text</label> ' + postfix + '</div>';
        $("#canvas").append(elemHtml);
        label++;
    }
    $(function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({containment: "#canvas"}).resizable();
    });
    return false;
});
```

JQuery Code to bind a Remove event:

```
$(".draggable").on("click", "i", function(){
     alert("going to remove this element");
});
```

But the Click event is not working as the drag-able element is triggering it's own event whenever I click on it.

How Can I make this Cross click-able.?

Comment: I'm sure there's an easier way, but my first thought is:  on `drop` of the object (basically when you let your mouse click go) find out if it has moved (get previous coordinates, get new coordinates).  If it has not moved, remove it

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code:

```
$(".draggable i.remove-elem").off('click').on("click", function(){
        $(this).parent('.draggable').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you got the same issue as here : [jQuery .on('click') does not work with jQuery UI draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578763/jquery-onclick-does-not-work-with-jquery-ui-draggable)

This should work:

```
$(".draggable i").on("click", function(){
     alert("going to remove this element");
});
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8dg76LL/1/)

Comment: This is not working. Actually the example link you have added is about **Making parent element of draggable element clickable.** But in my case, I want to make a child element clickable.

Comment: @user3130733 Ok. I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8dg76LL/1/) for you. Check it out. It works.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Please add an answer so that I can accept.